# How to manage external library dependencies for multiple entries in webpack?

Tags: webpack

In our projects, we have multiple webpack entries. They have dependencies for 3rd-party libraries (e.g. angularJS, fileAPI and so on). What we would like to achieve are:

- external dependencies will NOT be bundled together with the our own entries.
- external dependencies will be referenced separately. We don't want to reference them as a single bundle. As result, they can be loaded in parallel.
- these references could be fulfilled automatically. We hope to use `require` in our own entries and let webpack automatically load them for us.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve your first two bullet points.

1. Yes, external dependencies/libraries could be different entry point
   something like

   ```
   ...
   vendor: ["jquery", "underscore", ...],
   ...
   ```

   and add the `CommonsChunkPlugin` plugin to your plugin list.

   ```
   new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin("vendor", "vendor.bundle.js")
   ```
2. Ok, if you don't want to bundle them, and want to reference as a
   separate file, you can make separate entry point for each
   libs/dependencies or you can use script tags to load them separately.

   ```
   ...
   dep1: 'dep1',
   dep2: 'dep2',
   ...
   ```
3. No, you can't achieve this point as webpack bundles whatever
   `require`-d with your own entry point and their reference files until unless you use `code-splitting` feature.